# Ruby class method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :users

 def self.find_latest_closed
   Post.where("status=?",'Closed').order("updated_at DESC").limit(2)
 end

 def self.find_latest_open
   Post.where("status=?",'Open').order("updated_at DESC").limit(2)
 end
end
```

In PostController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def dashboard
  @totalclose = Post.find_latest_closed
   @totalopen = Post.find_latest_open
 end
end
```

I get the following error

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#dashboard
undefined method `find_latest_closed' for #<Class:0x000001074eb760>
```

Whats wrong here ?

Comment: Does it work in console?  Is the class definition in models/post.rb?  Also, check your spelling - these errors are commonly due to typos...

Comment: You should use scopes instead of class methods (ex: `scope :two_latest_open, where(status: 'Open').order('updated_at DESC').limit(2)`

Comment: Regardless of what's going on here, you would probably be better served using ```scope``` instead of defining your own method. ```scope :latest_closed, where('status=?', 'Closed').order('updated_at DESC').limit(2)```

Comment: It's possible you've got some sort of conflict with ActiveRecord's magic `find_*` methods.  Maybe try changing the method names to `get_*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible you've got some sort of conflict with ActiveRecord's magic `find_*` methods. Maybe try changing the method names to `get_*`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove the Post prefix of the method calls.

```
 def self.find_latest_closed
   where("status=?",'Closed').order("updated_at DESC").limit(2)
 end

 def self.find_latest_open
   where("status=?",'Open').order("updated_at DESC").limit(2)
 end
```